# Invoice API response with only 2 decimal places for field UnitAmount (Unit Price)

Tags: api, invoice, xero-api

Today i noticed, that Xero Accounting API, endpoint Invoices, Get Invoice returns array with LineItems.
The problem is, that API returns 2 decimal places for field UnitAmount,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSgl7.png)
but on UI we can see 3 decimal places (Unit Price)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGhCj.png)

FUN FACT:
Quantity is with 4 decimal places :)

How can i get UnitAmount with 3 decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try adding the unitdp=4 parameter in your GET call, this should override the default 2dp response

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i needed! :) 
I asked from curiosity, why unitdp=4 is not default value?
Quantity has 4 decimal places nomatter what param you pick :)

Comment: Yep, in my opinion it absolutely should be the default.  Not least because without this option the line totals are incorrect if more DP's have been used(!!!)